# Selenium/chrome Chrome asks for password to unlock keyring

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

On Ubuntu 16.04, chrome version: Google Chrome 52.0.2743.82 (Official Build) (64-bit)

When executing selenium/chrome code, I get chrome dialog box to unlock the key ring. Result is selenium code throwing exception

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died

From chrome drivers logs (collected via --verbose command) I see following

> [INFO]: Launching chrome: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-update --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-logging --ignore-certificate-errors --kiosk-printing --load-extension=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.JxYclx/extension_ockefobfkeddeiaoonaadekgljdlkbim,/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.JxYclx/internal --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12294 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection --start-maximized --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/dll/mydir

This is what I see in chromedriver log files when dialog box shows up

```
[75.725][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[75.725][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations
[75.745][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[375.779][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 299.188
[375.779][INFO]: Timed out. Stopping navigation...
[385.781][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
[385.781][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations
[385.781][INFO]: RESPONSE ClickElement timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.89)
[454.310][INFO]: COMMAND ClickElement {
   "id": "0.4153012592029841-13"
}
```

Interesting part is I get the dialog sometimes on login page, sometimes on other pages which has no password fields - it seems to be completely random and does not happen all the pages with/without password.

Comment: Is this any keyring timeout matter like your code is running for x minutes and keyring is set to prompt for every x minute?

Comment: @AbirKhan, don't think so. I have not set up keyring at all.